# How to split a sculpt into different parts to prepare for 3D printing?

Tags: sculpting, 3d-printing

I have a sculpted object that I want to break apart into several components and export each into separate STL files for printing.

For example, I want to separate the teeth parts from the gums so I can print and paint them separately. Separate the chin from the gums, and so on.

The geometry is simple enough that I can do it all by hand, going vertex by vertex, but that will take a long time and I'm wondering if there's a better way to split them via the sculpting tools. Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that a potential option is to enter edit mode when the object is selected, then hover your mouse over the part you want to separate, then press L. This highlights that part from the rest of the object. Then press p and separate the highlighted part by selection.